# XMonad set layout depending on which monitor it's displayed

Tags: haskell, xmonad

Is it possible to somehow make the workspace layout change depending on which physical screen I am displaying it?

I want to use reflectHoriz (from XMonad.Layout.PerWorkspace) on layouts on my left monitor so that the master pane is always closest to the center of 2 screens.

I tried XMonad.Layout.IndependentScreens but that just creates double monitor dependant workspaces and that's not what I'm aiming at. Ideally, I want the same workspace to have different layout set depending on the monitor on which it is displayed.

Comment: Does this help? https://www.reddit.com/r/xmonad/comments/fhzw3/permonitor_layout

Answer (score 3):

I think it should be possible to make a `Layout` wrapper (like [`Mirror`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.11/docs/XMonad-Layout.html#t%3aMirror) or `Choose`) which does what you want.  The `runLayout` method of [`LayoutClass`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.11/docs/XMonad-Core.html#t%3aLayoutClass) receives the `WorkspaceId`, which you can look up in the map from `Screen`s to `Workspace`s.